# Why one cannot use "is" to compare the numbers?

Tags: python, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python “is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Usually I use the `type(x) == type(y)` to compare if the types are the same. And then use`x==y` to compare if the numerical values are equal.

However, someone proposed that one may just use `z1 is z2` to compare if the `z1` and `z2` are containing the same type of numbers with exactly the same value. In many cases, it will be successful (especially for the positive ints).

However, sometimes the same number (mostly the negative ints) can have several different instances. Is this an expected behavior of python?

For example:

```
>>> for x in range(-20,125):
    z1=x
    z2=int(float(x))
    if z1 is not z2:
        print "z1({z1}; type = {typez1}; id={idz1}) is not z2({z2}; type = {typez2}; id={idz2})".format(z1=z1,typez1=type(z1),idz1=id(z1),z2=z2,typez2=type(z2),idz2=id(z2))


z1(-20; type = <type 'int'>; id=33869592) is not z2(-20; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870384)
z1(-19; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870480) is not z2(-19; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870408)
z1(-18; type = <type 'int'>; id=32981032) is not z2(-18; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870384)
z1(-17; type = <type 'int'>; id=33871368) is not z2(-17; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870408)
z1(-16; type = <type 'int'>; id=33869712) is not z2(-16; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870384)
z1(-15; type = <type 'int'>; id=33869736) is not z2(-15; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870408)
z1(-14; type = <type 'int'>; id=33869856) is not z2(-14; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870384)
z1(-13; type = <type 'int'>; id=33869280) is not z2(-13; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870408)
z1(-12; type = <type 'int'>; id=33868464) is not z2(-12; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870384)
z1(-11; type = <type 'int'>; id=33868488) is not z2(-11; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870408)
z1(-10; type = <type 'int'>; id=33869616) is not z2(-10; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870384)
z1(-9; type = <type 'int'>; id=33871344) is not z2(-9; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870408)
z1(-8; type = <type 'int'>; id=33869064) is not z2(-8; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870384)
z1(-7; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870336) is not z2(-7; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870408)
z1(-6; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870360) is not z2(-6; type = <type 'int'>; id=33870384)
>>> x
124
>>> print x
124
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.version
2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers has an answer for you as well

Comment: Who proposed that? They should be smacked.

Comment: This is true (in CPython) for a small subset of integers. This behavior should NOT be relied upon as it is not guaranteed to be identical across python implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Only a few numbers close to 0 (more positive than negative, as you've discovered) are **interned** by the compiler. Since an expression may result in a number outside this range, `is` should *never* be used to check for equality.

Comment: Do you know the range of those numbers? (I believe it's -5 to 256 inclusive). It also might be important to note that interning behavior is not guaranteed and might not be the same across all python implementations.

Comment: @JoelCornett it really doesn't matter which ones they are, since as you mentioned, it's implementation dependent.

Comment: The result of the expression is irrelevant. `is` should _never_ be used to check for equality (EVER), since the interning of ints is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Thanks! Actually it surprised me that the `is` can actually work for some numbers. So it is good to know there are some interned objects.

Comment: @Wang strike that from your memory, as you should never use it, even if it "works".

Comment: And it doesn't always work for the interned numbers either. I can't remember which functions, but some functions return new instances instead of the interned numbers. So never, ever, use "is" to check for numerical equality.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#is):

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true if and only if `x` and `y` are the same object. `x is not y` yields the inverse truth value.

So even if x and y are the same type and are equal, they might not satisfy the `is` relation.

Answer (score 0):

The only proper use of `is` is to compare equality of identity of objects. To compare equality of value, use `==`.

Answer (score 0):

The 'is' keyword compares the identity of two objects(basically the memory location at which they are stored), NOT the value. It should not be used to check for equality.

The 'is' keyword succeeded a few times in your case due to specifics of the implementation of your interpreter - some numbers are stored by your compiler for easy access. You should not expect or rely on this behavior.